# Problem with NSUndoManager

Tags: nsundomanager

I read the chapter on undo/redo in the Hillegass book. He only goes over document based applications though.  I am using pretty much the same code that is in the book, but I get "appController may not respond to -undoManager" when I use the code below.  I know that I have to create an Undo Manager explicitly, but exactly how do I do this.  Please give me a step by step explanation.  Thanks.

-(void)insertObject:(Accounts *)currentAccount inArrayOfAccountsAtIndex:(int)index
{
    NSLog(@"Adding %@ to %@", currentAccount, arrayOfAccounts);

```
NSUndoManager *undo = [self undoManager];

[[undo prepareWithInvocationTarget:self]
   removeObjectFromArrayOfAccountsAtIndex: index];
if(![undo isUndoing]){
    NSLog(@"After the if(![undo isUndoing]) statement");
    [undo setActionName:@"Insert Account"];
}

[arrayOfAccounts insertObject:currentAccount atIndex:index];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is the initialization of the Undo-Manager missing.

Try

```
NSUndoManager *undoManager;
```

at the beginning of your class and

```
undoManger = [NSUndoManager alloc] init];
```

in the initialization of your class (for example in "viewDidLoad").